# Get selected values from combo box PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, combobox

Hello I am creating a **Web GIS** with Codeigniter framework.
I am just facing a problem while Updating Location Data.

On my database I have table "location_category" with field: id_category (primarykey), name_category, icon_category

And also table "location" with field: id_location (primarykey), name_location, id_category (foreignkey to table location_category), lat, long.

So, the problem is where I updated a data location on it's category combobox, it doesn't pointed to selected location category.

This is **View** of location_edit.php

```html
<div class="form-group">
                  <label>Edit Location</label>
                  <br/>
                   <input name="id_location" type="hidden" value="<?=$d['id_location'] ?>">
                  <select name="location_category" class="form-control select2" style="width: 40%;">
                   <-- The problem should be here -->
                    <?php foreach ($dj->result() as $r) {
                      echo "<option value='$d->id_category'>$r->nama_category</option>";
                    } ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <input name="name_location" type="text" id="name_location" class="form-control" style="width:40%;" value="<?=$d['name_location'] ?>" required="">
                </div>
<div class="form-group">
                  <label>Latitude</label>
                  <input name="latitude" type="text" id="latitude" class="form-control" style="width:40%;" value="<?=$d['latitude'] ?>" required="">
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Longitude</label>
                  <input name="longitude" type="text" id="longitude" class="form-control" style="width:40%;" value="<?=$d['longitude'] ?>" required="">
                </div>
```

This is **Controller** of location_edit.php

```html
public function Location_edit($id)
 {
  $data['c'] = $this->db->get('location_category');
  $data['d'] = $this->db->get_where('location',array('id_location'=>$id))->row_array();
  $data['dj'] = $this->db->query("SELECT l.id_location, l.id_category, k.name_category FROM location as l, category as c WHERE l.id_category=c.id_category");
  $this->template->load('back-end/_template','back-end/_location_edit',$data);
 }
```

Comment: Please clear your question what you expect. Actually i didn't understand your question. Do you want selected drop-down value on editing??

Comment: Helo @KaziNayem yes right, I use drop-down selection on editing. But when I edit data, the drop-down value should returned to default value as showed when add data.

Comment: would you please explain what is data and id_data is your get_where?? you mentioned above that your tables are 'location' and 'location_category' but what would it mean data and id_data

Comment: @KaziNayem sorry it's mistyped. I mean data is location table, id_data is id_location. 
So there is 2 tables, location and location_category. :)

Comment: try to code structurally. use model for query and controller to get model data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your hidden value works perfectly then i think below code will help you surprisingly.

```
<select name="location_category" class="form-control select2" style="width: 40%;">
   <option value="">Select Something</option>
   <?php foreach($dj->result() as $r): ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $r->id_category; ?>" <?php if($r->id_category==$d['id_location']) { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>><?php echo $r->nama_category; ?></option>
   <?php endforeach; ?> 
</select>
```

Comment: it's my pleasure, dear. go ahead.